# How to get Unix Time stamp as 00:00:00

Tags: unix-timestamp

Is there any command to get Timestamp as 00:00:00

Basically i need Current Date with Time stamp as 00:00:00 in unix

I tried

$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' 00:00:00)

But i need actual command in unix for it instead of appending 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string in the format `2020-02-05 00:00:00` then how about just using `echo` to print the date output of the `date` command and then appending the time?

Like

```
echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried as string before as you said but i was getting below error.  Exception:com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input:

Comment: @San How do you use this command? What is it supposed to be used for? Please edit your question ask about the *real* problem you try to solve.